# Преобразование строки в дату

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема. Мне нужно преобразовать паттерн вида "dd MMM yyyy" в LocalDate, но постоянно выбрасывает, с одной стороны, понятный, с другой - непонятный эксепшен "Text '16 Sep 2006' could not be parsed at index 3".

```
 import java.time.LocalDate;
 import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
 ...

 String date1 = "16 Sep 2006";
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy");
 LocalDate dateLocal = LocalDate.parse(date1, formatter);
```

Пробовал разные вариации паттернов, но всегда одно и то же, вроде ведь должно работать. :/

Comment: Локаль проверьте свою - такое ощущение, что ожидается `16 Сен 2006` - `index 3` - как раз показывает на первый символ месяца

Comment: @Barmaley, хмм, интересная идея, но аналогичный результат с index 3.

Comment: `16 сен 2006` сен со строчной буквой

Comment: @cadmy, не друг, такой вариант тоже не идет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После недолгих изысканий оказалось, что в случае с DateTimeFormatter, помимо шаблона, нужно указывать еще и стиль форматирования, если в строке встречаются буквенные обозначения месяца или дня. Также важно заметить, что если строка только в числовом виде, то стиль форматирования можно не указывать. Вот такие отличия от простого DateFormatter, где достаточно только шаблона.

Спасибо участнику [Barmaley](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648/barmaley), навел на нужную мысль про Locale.

**Вариант 1**:

```
java.util.Locale locale = java.util.Locale.US;
String input = "January 2, 2010";
String pattern = "MMMM d, yyyy";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern,locale);
LocalDate dateLocal = LocalDate.parse(input, formatter);
```

**Вариант 2**:

```
 String input = "16 Sep 2006";
 String pattern = "dd MMM yyyy";
 //Далее, как с Вариантом 1
```